# How to build workshop

Tags: art-of-conquest

I got a new mission that says that I need to build a level 1 workshop.

My castle is already level 7 and I have no option to build the workshop. I have already lurked what are the building that I can build with the castle at level 8 and I keep not having the option to build the workshop.

Do I need to increase the level of the castle (higher than level 8) to have the opportunity to build the workshop or is there another way to built it?